# How can I read PostScript files?

Tags: files, default-applications

Is there a way to read PostScript files on Android? Currently when I click on a PostScript file web link it downloads it then takes no further action, unlike a pdf.

Comment: [42 results on a search for postscript](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=postscript). Have you checked those apps?

Comment: @Izzy Once you filter for Free you get one file format converter and one that uses google docs.  I don't see any that just let you read a postscript file in that list.

Comment: I didn't check them all. A raw scan shows [Prompterous](http://www.appbrain.com/app/prompterous/com.labotec.teleprompter) fits your description, but doesn't come for free (1 buck, so it will make you bankrupt); [DocsViewer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/docs-viewer/com.meltingsource.DocsViewer) would even fit better and comes for free (but needs Google Docs, yeah, so it wouldn't be my choice either). OK, was just a start. So I've to leave the place for better answerers ;)

Comment: "Prompterous is the first App who turns your Android Tablet into a powerful teleprompter !" This doesn't look right either.